# Is there a software that provides access to google speech-to-text on a PC desktop?

Tags: speech-recognition

Google has speech to text in the google search page, but is it possible to access the same API/functionality for general purpose speech to text conversion on the windows PC, outside of the browser?

Comment: For Ubuntu: [google2ubuntu](https://github.com/benoitfragit/google2ubuntu)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not surę if the goal is to use google services or transcribe the speech, but if you need windows desktop software that can transcribe any system audio then Hintscribe can do it.

Hintscribe is not using google, but vosk modele that can do transcription offline. It is also integrated with ChatGpt do you can select any portion of a transcription in real time and prompt it about.